# How to add Image in Tile List

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am using Flex Builder 3.0 and i want to add image in tile list dynamically then how its possible.
Images are stored in Images folder of src. and my array is similar like that.

```
private var arrImage:Array = [
            {source:"Images/1.png",tooltip:"1"},
            {source:"Images/2.png",tooltip:"2"},
            {source:"Images/3.png",tooltip:"3"},
            {source:"Images/4.png",tooltip:"4"},
            {source:"Images/5.png",tooltip:"5"},
            {source:"Images/6.png",tooltip:"6"},
            {source:"Images/7.png",tooltip:"7"},
            {source:"Images/8.png",tooltip:"8"},
            {source:"Images/9.png",tooltip:"9"},
            {source:"Images/10.png",tooltip:"10"}];
```

my tile list dataprovider is arrImage.

Comment: I want to show tool tip when i will rollover on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try this Code.....

```
 private var arrImage:Array = [
            {source:"Images/1.png",tooltip:"1"},
            {source:"Images/2.png",tooltip:"2"},
            {source:"Images/3.png",tooltip:"3"},
            {source:"Images/4.png",tooltip:"4"},
            {source:"Images/5.png",tooltip:"5"},
            {source:"Images/6.png",tooltip:"6"},
            {source:"Images/7.png",tooltip:"7"},
            {source:"Images/8.png",tooltip:"8"},
            {source:"Images/9.png",tooltip:"9"},
            {source:"Images/10.png",tooltip:"10"}];


  <mx:TileList id="tileList" dataProvider="{arrImage}" columnCount="1" columnWidth="100"
    useRollOver="false" selectable="false" backgroundAlpha="0" borderStyle="none" 
    rowHeight="65" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" >
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalGap="0"
                verticalAlign="middle" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                <mx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.controls.Alert;
                        override public function set data(value:Object):void
                        {
                            if(value !=null)
                            {
                                super.data = value;
                                if(img !=null)
                                {
                                    img.source = data.source;
                                    img.toolTip = data.tooltip;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]]>
                </mx:Script>
                <mx:Image id="img" />
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:TileList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iconField` property for this.

For example in your case:

```
<mx:TileList dataProvider="{arrImage}" iconField="source"/>
```

Read the [livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TileList.html#propertySummary) for more info on this.

Comment: thanks dennis... Great answers...
but i also want tooltip. so is it any possible way for that..